# How to return a result from a generator calling an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, koa, node-postgres

I'm using the Koa framework and ES6. How do I get the first method to return a result to this view function that requires a `yield`? I am trying to use the pg library, which uses asynchronous calls, in a node 7.5 app.

```
pgrepo.listCities = function*() {
   pool.query('SELECT distinct(town) from public.property_uk', function(err, result) {
     console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result.rows));
     // What now?
   });
};

www.pgindex = function*() {
   let results = yield pgrepo.listCities();  // What now?

   console.log('handler: ' + results)

   yield this.render('pgindex', {
       items: results
   });
}
```

I understand what is happening, the `yield` is deferring execution, so the function runs and yields with no results, and then the query fires and produces results.

So, my question is, how can I refactor these 2 functions so that the query results are returned to the function that wants to pass them to the view.

Comment: Are you sure you want generators? The first function doesn't yield anything, the second yields different types of data. It seems you rather need async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't thinking of answering because I have no idea about Koa / generators and what not, but can't you pull this off with simple promise? (Since no body else is posting, figured at least to try to give you some way that you might be able to solved it)

This code is not tested, and I have no idea about your stack, so this is only here as possible solution in case that you have a bit more freedom with code

```
// Since I have no idea why generators should be used here, let's remove the *
// if you really do need it, then this answer might not work (as I said, I never
// even touched generator functions, so I will just make this as arrow fn)

pgrepo.listCities = () => {
  // first let's return a promise to function call
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query('SELECT distinct(town) from public.property_uk', function(err, result) {
      // since this is in callback, we can be sure that this will be executed
      // when the query itself is finished. because this is a promise we
      // can now here resolve it here with results. but first check for
      // errors and reject if this query failed
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result.rows);
    });
  });
};

www.pgindex = () => {
  // Since I have no idea why generators should be used here, let's remove the
  // yield...
  let results = pgrepo.listCities;  

  // now our results can call the listCities and get the promise
  // back as result. as soon as that promise is resolved we can enter into .then
  // and access values

  results()
    .then((results) => {
      // this console log should now have all the results from the query.
      console.log(results);

      // you can now do here what you want with the data. again not sure how
      // this can play with generators

      // also this (both this as next commented block and this as pointer) will
      // most likely fail due to arrow function changing context of this, so you
      // might wanna play around with that to be sure you have correct context
      // if it doesn't work out of the box. If you can't figure it you, you can
      // change this arrow function in normal 'function (results) {...}' and your
      // context will be fine and you will be able to call proper this (I think :) )
      this.render('pgindex', {
        items: results
      });
    }) // and ofc error handling
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Something went wrong and I am terrible error message ' + err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the co-routines version of your code which make your promises look like syncronous code by hiding its async nature. Instead `.then`ing promises, you can yield them, and have your code would look like this:

```
let co = require('co');
let pg = require('co-pg')(require('pg'));

let connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:1234@localhost/postgres';

co(function* connectExample() {
    try {
        let client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
        yield client.connectPromise();

        let result = yield client.queryPromise('SELECT distinct(town) from public.property_uk');
        console.log(result);

        client.end();
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
    }
});
```

This is similar to async/await but you can use it today! (although at the time of writing, async/await is entering Node very soon)

Notice that I've **promisified** the `pg` module so it can be used with `co`

Answer (score 0):

Without the need to reinvent anything, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) supports ES6 generators out of the box:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*initialization options*/);
var db = pgp(/*your connection details*/);

function * getCities(t) {
    var cities = yield t.query('SELECT distinct(town) from public.property_uk');

    // do whatever you need here

    return cities;
}

function * Generator_Caller() {
    try {
        var cities = yield db.task(getCities);
        console.log(cities);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function Regular_Caller() {
    db.task(getCities)
        .then(function (cities) {
            console.log(cities);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help, the final code I went with that worked is:

```
pgrepo.listTowns = function*() {
var results = yield pool.query('SELECT distinct(town) from public.property_uk');
return results;    };

www.pgindex = function*() {
const results = yield pgrepo.listTowns();

console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results.rows));

yield this.render('pgindex', {
    items: results.rows
});};
```